# Prevent copy paste of url in another tab using form authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

Please help me on Preventing copy paste of url in another tab.

I am using forms authentication for my application.
I had logged in accessed some pages.

Now if i paste that accessed pages url ...i can access this page without login also

i tried adding following code..but no use..still im able to see the pages without login

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="Authen" protection="All" timeout="60" loginUrl="login.aspx"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
<deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

how to stop the page access without login (even copy and paste the URL) ?

Answer (score 0):

That code is correct to stop any anonymous use of your website.

I suspect the case is something like the user is just shutting a tab or browser and not logging off via a link or some such mechanism. In this case IIS will not be able to log the user out correctly.

Are you sure the users cookie is not still valid when they paste a url into a browser? i.e. they are still technically logged in?

Try actually logging off via a link and then try pasting the url into another tab / browser, this should result in the user being asked to log back in.

Try just closing the tab and then try pasting the url into a new tab, this should result in the user going to the URL as they are still logged in.

You could as a test reduce your timeout to say 1 minute and retest.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in page_Load()

```
 string strPreviousPage = "";
     if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
       {
        strPreviousPage = Request.UrlReferrer.Segments[Request.UrlReferrer.Segments.Length - 1];          
        }        
    if(strPreviousPage =="")
        {
          Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
         }
```

Credits [Asheej Kommery's](https://weblogs.asp.net/varadam/how-to-restrict-the-user-to-copy-and-paste-the-url-in-browser-address-bar-in-asp-net-web)